# How to maximize the pickups and deliveries instead of minimizing arc costs?

Tags: or-tools

So far I am using the routing package of ortools with the arc cost evaluator:

```
costCallbackIndex = model.registerTransitCallback(this::costCallback);
model.setArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(costCallbackIndex);
```

But I have realized that I am more interested in maximizing the number of pickups and deliveries (they are optional, using `model.addDisjunction` with a drop penalty) than the overall sum of meters travelled. Since I am dealing with a lot of pickups and deliveries I don't want to put the extra strain of minimizing arc costs on the solver.

One option is to define a arc cost callback that always returns 0, but this might confuse the solver. I could also not call the method `setArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles` and hence suggest to the solver that I am not interested in arc costs.

What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just refrain from using `setArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles` ?

Comment: Ok, so my worry was that the ortools routing problems have this inbuilt requirement for minimizing arc costs.